# Verify recruiter identity contacting via Stack Overflow Jobs

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was recently contacted by a recruiter for Amazon Advertising through Stack Overflow jobs, asking if they can call me to discuss an opening and requested my updated resume.  It feels a little too good to be true, so I started digging to see if I could verify their identity.  However, I'm having a hard time doing so.  Their email address has a "@amazon.com" domain name and the phone number is a Seattle, WA number (though I can't tell exactly where it's coming from) which is all good signs, but everything in their message is publicly available information.

Does Stack Overflow Jobs verify its recruiters or its members in any way?  Are there any other tools I can use to verify that this is a legitimate recruiter?  I'd like to go forward with this, but I could easily see this being a scammer trying to get some information out of me.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, recruiters using Stack Overflow Jobs actually need to pay stuff, and they are not able to just spam everybody just like that either (there is a limit in how many people they can contact at the same time). So it’s *likely* that recruiters contacting you through the platform usually do so sincerely.

Comment: Good luck and congrats on a "too-good-to-be-true"-seeming job offer :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Amazon advertises a large number of jobs with us and they actively use our candidate search product so the likelihood is that this is not a scam. If the message came from SO jobs rather than via direct email then their email address will have been validated as part of the sign up process.

If it was a direct mail then we can make no guarantees.

If you're not sure then drop a note to `careers@stackoverflow.com` and we can verify that the message came from them.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That makes me feel much better about this.  The initial email came from SO Jobs, but then they followed up via email (I guess my email address was shared with them when I clicked the "I'm Interested" button).

Comment: Yup, that's correct, as soon as you click that they can see your contact details.